# Is it rape to have sex with a man without disclosing that one is a male-to-female transgender person?

Tags: criminal-law, sexual-assault, transgender

A male-to-female transgender person meets a male partner, but does not tell the partner about being transgender. Thus, the male partner believes the transgender woman is a (cis-gender) woman, and they have sex. If the transgender woman hadn't hidden this fact, the male partner would not ever have wanted to have sex.

Is this considered rape?

---

Considering the growing ratio of people going through a sex change operation, and living later hiding this fact from the society, the problem will likely become more and more common.

Comment: The question tries to be country-independent, but if it would result its closure, then we could assume U.S. law.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119992/discussion-on-question-by-gray-sheep-is-it-rape-to-have-sex-with-a-man-without-d).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**tl;dr**: It might be rape, but it depends.

There is the concept of [rape by deception](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_by_deception), which might apply here. However, that concept is usually only applied under very narrow circumstances - not every act of deception in a relationship can be used to later claim rape by deception.

---

There was a related case **in England** in 2015, where the situation was reversed to your question: A woman pretended to be a man as a means having sex with another woman. She was sentenced to eight years in prison. BBC article: [Woman who posed as man jailed for sex assaults](http://www.bbc.com/news/uk-england-34799692). However, in that case the accused never claimed to be transgender, she just falsely claimed to be a man. In the case of a transgender person, some would claim that their "new" gender is the real gender, so a court might decide differently.

Wikipedia lists another case **in Massachusetts**, where a woman had sex with her boyfriend's brother because he claimed to be the boyfriend. In that case the brother was found not guilty, because in Massachusetts rape by definition has to involve force:

> (b) Whoever has sexual intercourse or unnatural sexual intercourse
>   with a person and compels such person to submit by force and against
>   his will, or compels such person to submit by threat of bodily injury
>   [...]

*[Commonwealth of Massacusetts, General Laws, Section 22](https://malegislature.gov/Laws/GeneralLaws/PartIV/TitleI/Chapter265/Section22)*

**In Germany**, I could not find any similar cases. However, in the German criminal code, the definition of rape includes:

> 1. der Täter ausnutzt, dass die Person nicht in der Lage ist, einen entgegenstehenden Willen zu bilden oder zu äußern,
>
> [...]
>
> 3. der Täter ein Überraschungsmoment ausnutzt,

English:

> 1. the offender uses the fact that the person is unable to form or to express a contrary will
>
> [...]
>
> 3. the offender uses a moment of surprise

*[Strafgesetzbuch (StGB) -
§ 177 Sexueller Übergriff; sexuelle Nötigung; Vergewaltigung](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/stgb/__177.html), translation mine*

So, again, a court *could* decide that the use of a deception causes the victim to be "unable to form a contrary will". However, courts will have to decide each case individually.

Comment: "einen entgegenstehenden Willen zu bilden" I can't imagine a court ruling it was rape based on that paragraph. Having undergone sex change operation doesn't magically cause other people to no longer be able to say "no".

Comment: You seem to assume that not disclosing "by the way, I changed my gender" is a deception.

Comment: @Brandin: Yes, it might be considered a deception by omission. I'm not judging whether it is (I don't know myself, I'm not a specialist lawyer), I just pointed out what the law says and that this is one way this could be considered rape, if a court sees it that way. If you have something to add which shows that this would not be considered deception, by all means go ahead and write an answer (or edit mine).

Comment: No, but both of your examples cited are clearly deception. The statement "the situation was reversed to your question" in particular is misleading; it was not reversed. As you say, transgenderism was not even involved in that case, and there was clear deception.

Comment: "By the way, I changed my gender" is not how being transgender worked. They don't change their gender. They change their appearance to make it match their gender at last. The transgender woman in the question was always a woman, it just wasn't obvious to the people around her for a long time.

Comment: @gnasher729 That is exactly the question. Your definition is a popular definition that many are using today. Go back 50 or 100 years, and most people would have had a very different understanding of the subject. And while your view is definitley a nice way to treat the matter, it is not an indisputable, fundamental truth, same as any other way of viewing any other aspect of human experience. As such it is very possible to have different views than yours, and in the end, the answer to the question heavily depends on how the law and the judge view this matter.

Comment: @gnasher729 It also matters greatly on the jurisdiction. In the US or most of Europe, chances are, the law and judge will see it in a similar light as you. On the other hand, I wouldn't bet much on getting the same outcome in Afghanistan, Iran or Russia.

Answer (score 15):

Not disclosing transgender identity is not a crime of any kind, not rape, not fraud, not anything else. There is really no qualification to this statement.

There is pretty much no plausible scenario in which concealing a transgender identity leads to liability for fraud of any kind and this never constitutes rape by deception.

What is a crime and is regularly prosecuted, is retaliating against the person or property of someone who they discover is transgender while having sex. Incidents like these happen with some frequency and they alway create criminal liability for the person retaliating and never for the transgender individual in the cases where the transgender individual isn't killed (dozens of time each year in the U.S. the transgender individual is killed in a situation like this one).

Comment: Your last paragraph is not relevant to the question. Besides, whether the retaliation was criminal would depend on the actions. Unfriending the partner from social media as retaliation is almost certainly not a crime. Verbal or physical threats probably are, whether as retaliation or not.

Comment: I clarified the statement. But, it is relevant as it clarifies how the situations in question play out legally in practice.

Comment: While I respect your experience - are you sure it is this clear-cut? As far as I understand, if a jurisdiction has "rape by deception" (which not all do), a judge _might_ consider this rape by deception. Or is there some specific language in these laws which rules that out?

Comment: Rape by deception is an extremely narrow doctrine adopted in only a few jurisdictions and generally with quite explicit statutory or case law language that wouldn't reach these circumstances. See e.g. prior SE answer https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/23845/is-it-rape-to-have-sex-with-a-man-without-disclosing-that-one-is-a-male-to-femal/23856?noredirect=1#comment40994_23856 Neither of the UK grounds would apply. The "nature and purpose" clause applies to e.g. fake gynecologists and fake strip searches allegedly by police. If the sex is for purpose of pleasurable sex it doesn't apply.

Comment: There is an overview article at http://digitalcommons.law.yale.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5956&context=fss_papers but it is loading slowly for me today so I can't quote it.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the paper (it loads now); I'll have a look. Do you mind if I edit some quotes into your answer? Also, your link to the "prior SE answer" above links to my comment - did you want to link to a different answer?

Comment: I would mind if you edit quotes into my answer. Feel free to provide your own answer with citations to the relevant material. The link was supposed to be to https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/22486/is-it-rape-if-someone-goes-by-a-pseudonym-and-gave-fake-facts-about-themselves?rq=1 my apologies for the link.

Comment: "Not disclosing transgender identity is not a crime of any kind, not rape, not fraud, not anything else. There is really no qualification to this statement." It is a consent violation. "There is pretty much no plausible scenario in which concealing a transgender identity leads to liability for fraud of any kind and this never constitutes rape by deception" So if someone hires a sex worker thinking they are a biological woman, and they are not, that's not fraud?

Comment: @Acccumulation Not in U.S. law. There might be a jurisdiction where it is a crime to be transgender at all somewhere in the world.

Comment: Your response is a non sequitur, and implies that I was asserting that being transgender is a crime, which is a bizarre straw man.

Answer (score 2):

No, at least in the US, there is no criminal or even tortious liability stated here.

Answer (score 1):

Since the question was asked jurisdiction-independend, I'll try to answer it that way.

This greatly depends on the jurisdiction.

In general, I'd say, about any country that allows people to legally change their gender will not consider this rape. Because, in the eyes of the law, this person *is* a woman. So legally, there is nothing to hide.

In countries, where that's not the case, the outcome might be very different. There, since the person is legally still a man, that could be considered as hiding material information. Then the question is whether that jurisdiction has something like "rape by deception", and on how that is exactly defined.

Also, things might be different, if a person says, they identify as the other gender, but haven't changed their legal status. This might also be an issue, but again, only if the jurisdiction has "rape by deception" and then only if it actually encompasses that behaviour.

Answer (score -4):

Not disclosing a material fact does not constitute rape. Falsifying information, or not disclosing or lying would be a crime. Not of a criminal offense.

Comment: The question is whether not disclosing information in order to have sex would be considered rape. Your answer seems to disregard that. If you mean to say that lying or omitting information in order to get willingness to have sex is not a crime, make it clear that that's what you're saying.

Comment: Concealing one's transgender status from a potential sexual partner is not a crime of any kind, nor for that matter is it a tort.

Comment: Usually to consent to sex, people look at each other while dressed, later look at each other while undressed, and decide based on that. There’s no requirement to tell the other person your whole life story. Might be different if the other person had asked and you lied to them.